What is a more flexible way of storing parameters for an SQL table?
In my budget tracking app using Python and sqlite3 I don't need the user to come up with new types of transactions or accounts (card, cash and etc.). I need to make a fixed amount of transaction types (income, expense and transfer) and that's it. My code:
def make_a_transaction(current_cursor, account: str, type_of_transaction: str, category: str,
                       amount: float, currency: str = 'USD',
                       date_of_transaction: str = str(datetime.now())[:19], description_of_transaction: str = ''):
    current_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Transactions (account, type_of_transaction, category, amount, currency, '
                           'date_of_transaction, description_of_transaction) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                           (account, type_of_transaction, category, amount, currency,
                            date_of_transaction, description_of_transaction))

I don't want to let the user create a new account, type of transaction, categories nor currency. I could write:
cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM Transactions')
if category not in cursor.fetchall():
    print('Choose category from the list of existing categories')

But is there a more flexible approach? Maybe a JSON file or another SQL table?

Do not change questions in a way that invalidates posted answers please (ask a new question instead).

cursor.fetchall() returns a list of tuples. Unless category is also a tuple, the if condition will always be true.

It would be more efficient to let the database do the work of determining that some category be not present in the table.  You could try something along these lines:
query = '''SELECT EXISTS (
               SELECT 1 FROM category WHERE category = ?
           )'''
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
if not result:
    print('Choose category from the list of existing categories')

